# Report error: Bad menu record in database

Tags: civireport

I'm using drupal 7 with CiviCRM 4.4.6

This error appear frequently when I view my report (including dashboard):

```
Bad item

Array
(
    [path] => /6
)
```

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
>   Bad menu record in database
>   Return to home page.

The path "/6" differ according to the report ID.

I'm not sure how this could happen, and when this error appear, all civicrm related functions will show error.

Anyone know what's the problem and how to solve it?

Addition:
After following @Prem Patel suggestion, this is what I found in ***/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog file

```
Nov 26 17:17:19  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/warrior/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(322): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/warrior/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(239): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Bad menu record in database")
#2 /home/warrior/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(72): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:1))
#3 /home/warrior/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#4 /home/warrior/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(456): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#5 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("report", "instance", "6")
#6 /home/warrior/www/www/includes/menu.inc(517): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3))
#7 /home/warrior/www/www/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#8 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check after rebuilding the civicrm menu. You will get more details in your civicrm log file. Just enabled the debugging and logging from below link

site-name/civicrm/admin/setting/debug?reset=1

***/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

Comment: I found the file, and I had paste the record in question above. But still, I can't understand what's happening

Comment: How did you rebuild the civicrm menu?  You need to delete the civicrm_navigation table records from database the import the civicrm_navigation.sql file (you will get get this file under sql folder of civicrm).  After importing the sql file don't forget to clear the cache and also delete civicrm temp folder (file/civicrm/template_c).   Before doing above process please take your database backup.